# Error when I use cordova platform add ios

Tags: ios, cordova, cordova-3

I tried running command `cordova platform add ios` but when the command is executed always appears an error like in the picture.

[image: iOS Error]

How do I fix this?

Note:

I use NodeJS v0.10.25

Comment: because you are using windows os

Comment: This happen as a consequence of not reading the documentation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Prerequisites

Before running any command-line tools, you need to install SDKs for each platform you wish to target.
To add support or rebuild a project for any platform, you need to run the command-line interface from the same machine that supports the platform's SDK. The CLI supports the following combinations:

iOS (Mac)
Android (Mac, Linux)
Blackberry (Mac, Windows)
Windows Phone 7 (Windows)
Windows Phone 8 (Windows)

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/guide_platforms_ios_index.md.html